# How to store data from JSON file into array and hashes?

Tags: ruby

```
require 'json'
file = File.read('\Users\ninetynine\Desktop\Boundless_drop_case_study\data\boundless.json')

data_hash = JSON.parse(file)
puts data_hash
```

now I want to store data from JSON file into array and hashes in ruby programming ?

Comment: `JSON.parse(file)` already converts the content of your file into Ruby structures. Please clarify what output are you expecting, and what you get.

Comment: i have josn file that contains data ,, i wana load the given JSON file into Ruby built-in data structures (hashes and arrays). and update the `jobs` property to an array of instances of 
class `Job`

Answer (score 0):

The `JSON.parse` converts the raw json data into a hash for you. You're already done. To access a member of the hash use `data_hash["key"]`

See the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org//stdlib-2.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#label-Parsing+JSON)